# Why can't I create html from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is my javascript code(**create.js**):

```
var stuff = document.querySelector(".stuff");


var item = document.createElement('div');
item.className = 'item';

stuff.appendChild(item);
```

and this is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sound Create</title>
    <script src="create.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="stuff">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I go on Developer Tools, no code is added. Thank you!

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements. You have to operate on each one in the list individually.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. But it's still not working

Comment: *What* was a "typo"?

Comment: Try `stuff[0].appendChild(item);` as your last line of JS. Does that work?

Comment: The "getElementsByClassName" function.

Comment: No. It does not work. It is giving me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Comment: Nothing is working because of the ↑ issue here.

Comment: Your '<script src="create.js"></script>` element is at the top of the page so it is being run before the HTML below it is added to the page, hence your `div.stuff` doesn't yet exist.
Possible suggestions:

Put the `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>` instead. Or:
Put your js in a function that gets run on load or on click of a button etc

Comment: Thank you quys! That was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

When you call "getElementsByClassName", you will get a LIST of HTML elements, even if it contains only one element. So the right way is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("stuff")[0];
```

Another way is using id. It's like ,  in js file, use document.getElementById('staff'). It returns the element directly, because id is always unique.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it is giving this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at create.js:6